# chdir in Vim doesn't work

Tags: vim

I'm in the mode of browsing a directory. How can I change the current directory to that one I'm browsing? At least manually. But ":chdir ." doesn't work

Moreover, in the config file I have "set autochdir" and it still doesn't change it always automatically

Comment: The default browsing tool is netrw.  While browsing, you could edit the directory you wish to browse (e.g. check help, `help netrw-browser`).  With respect to ":chdir ." not working, could you explain what you mean by not working.

Comment: @PatrickBacon, it doesn't change the working directory.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `:Explore` while editting a buffer and it will open a new buffer with a Netwr Directory Listing fot the dir the file is in.  This does not need `autochdir` to work.